# KV file popup does not respond with proper action

Tags: kivy, popup

My popup.KV file content:

```
<ConfirmPopup>:
cols:1
Label:
    text: root.text
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 1, 0.4
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
GridLayout:
    cols: 2
    size_hint_y: None
    height: '44sp'
    Button:
        text: 'Yes'
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 1, 0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
        on_release: root.dispatch('on_answer','yes')
    Button:
        text: 'No'
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
        on_release: root.dispatch('on_answer', 'no')
```

and the popup.PY file:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class ConfirmPopup(GridLayout):
    text = StringProperty('AAAA')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.register_event_type('on_answer')
        super(ConfirmPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_answer(self, *args):
        pass


class PopupTest():
    def __init__(self):
        self.popup = None

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file('popup.kv')

        content = ConfirmPopup(text='Do You Love Kivy?')
        content.bind(on_answer=self._on_answer)

        self.popup = Popup(title="Answer Question",
                           content=content,
                           size_hint=(None, None),
                           size=(480, 400),
                           auto_dismiss=False)
        self.popup.open()

    def _on_answer(self, instance, answer):
        print("USER ANSWER: ", repr(answer))
        self.popup.dismiss()

def show():
    pop = PopupTest()
    pop.build()
```

THis is the app.py file that uses the popup

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App

from popup import *


class PopTest(App):
    show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PopTest().run()
```

My problem is that the popup displays correctly, the buttons blink when clicked BUT the appropriate message is not printed and the popup is not dismissed when a button is clicked. To me it looks like the button event is not bound to the actions. How do I fix it.
Thanks for a fix and any explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Your `PopupTest` class must be an `EventDispatcher` in order for your code to work as you want. Just modify `PopupTest` slightly:

```
class PopupTest(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PopupTest, self).__init__()
        self.popup = None
```

Comment: Thanks John, I suspected it to be something simple but  my lack of knowledge prevented me from getting the right answer. Please what indicated to you what was wron so that I do not make a similar error again. Keep Well